# Multiple COUNT REGEX matches inside double CASE to fetch two vars. Can I make this better?

Tags: mysql

I'm using several counts inside CASES to create ranking values for two query result vars.

The following code is in fact a left outer join inside a bigger query and as you may guess, it slow things down a little. 
Is there a way to improve this? I'm over this code for hours now, any help is appreciated.

```sql
SELECT
U.id,
COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') AS leMatchesCount,

COALESCE( 
    (CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') = 6 THEN 3.33
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') = 5 THEN 2.75 
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') < 5 AND COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') >= 2 THEN 1.11
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') = 1 THEN 0.55
    END)
, 0) AS leRank1,

IF(MATCH(C.assets_animal_name) AGAINST ("any animal" IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1.11,
COALESCE(
    (CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') = 6 THEN 1.11
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') = 5 THEN 0.88 
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') < 5 AND COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') >= 2 THEN 0.37
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows') = 1 THEN 0.18
        END)
, 0)) AS leRank2

FROM
us3r U

LEFT OUTER JOIN assets_animals C ON
C.user_id = U.id AND C.assets_animal_name IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows')

GROUP BY
U.id
```

**Edit1:**

The query is built on the fly and I don't know the number of parameters used for the ranking.

Inside the CASE, each of the 4 WHEN lines try to match a dynamic number (here 6) and rate each match as *(calculations are made on the server side, this is a logical output)*:

```sql
WHEN = 6 rank = 5.00
WHEN = (6-1) rank = 3.80
WHEN < (6-1) AND > 2 = 2.90
WHEN = 1 rank = 1.11
```

Note that on the third line, the code checks for **"<"** previous value BUT **">"** 2.

Using the COUNT outside the WHEN, as **Ross Smith II** pointed out, won't allow me to use operands like **"<"** inside the WHEN.

<strike>For the first two and the last WHEN, no comparison signs are required, so hey, I can make 6 counts instead of 10 now, so each CASE would look like this:</strike>

```sql
COALESCE( 
    (CASE COUNT(C.assets_animal_name IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows'))
        WHEN 6 THEN 3.33
        WHEN 5 THEN 2.75 
        WHEN COUNT(C.assets_animal_name IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows') < 5 AND COUNT(C.assets_animal_name IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows') >=2 THEN 1.11
        WHEN 1 THEN 0.55
    END)
, 0) AS leRank1,
```

<strike>This simple change saved some precious milliseconds. Thanks.</strike>

**Edit2:**

I'm tired. I just wrote **"Using COUNT outside the WHEN won't allow operands inside WHEN"**. That means that on the example above the third line will be true for 0 matching records.

**Edit3:**

```sql
C structure: id(INT,P),assets_animal_name(VARCHAR), uid(FK->U)
U structure: id(INT,P), email(VARCHAR)
```

Sample data:

```sql
C
1,cats,1
2,dogs,1
3,birds,1
4,birds,2
5,rats,2
6,horses,2
7,cows,2
8,cats,2

U
1, jdoe@aol.com
2, mjoe@aol.com
```

Result data for REGEXP '^(cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows)$':

```sql
1, 5, 2.75, 0.88
2, 3, 1.11, 0.37
```

Comment: Wow. This begs to be completely refactored in terms of GROUP BY.  Can you give the table definitions and some sample data?

Comment: Table C is MyISAM and I'm ranking the number of occurrences of C matches on the fly. Table U is a simple user table with his id, mail and such, used here to display a user matches ranking. Data would be like userid1 have 3 animals on C and userid2 have 6, the WHERE rank the result based on query matches.

Comment: Can you add this information to the original post (and delete the comment)? Also give 10-20 sample rows of table C and matching U rows.

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
REGEXP 'cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows'
```

will match `brats` as well as `rats`. You probably want:

```
IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows')
```

or perhaps

```
REGEXP '^(cats|dogs|birds|rats|horses|cows)$'
```

Second, if you replace `CASE WHEN x` with `CASE x WHEN`, that will simplify things a bit.

Finally, I would move the final JOIN clause to a WHERE, as it's not really JOINing the tables.

Here's the rewritten query:

```
SELECT
    U.id,
    COUNT(C.assets_animal_name IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows')) AS leMatchesCount,
    COALESCE( 
        (CASE COUNT(C.assets_animal_name IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows'))
            WHEN 6 THEN 3.33
            WHEN 5 THEN 2.75 
            WHEN 4 THEN 1.11
            WHEN 3 THEN 1.11
            WHEN 2 THEN 1.11
            WHEN 1 THEN 0.55
        END)
    , 0) AS leRank1,
    IF(MATCH(C.assets_animal_name) AGAINST ("any animal" IN BOOLEAN MODE), 1.11,
    COALESCE(
        (CASE COUNT(C.assets_animal_name IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows'))
            WHEN 6 THEN 1.11
            WHEN 5 THEN 0.88 
            WHEN 4 THEN 0.37
            WHEN 3 THEN 0.37
            WHEN 2 THEN 0.37
            WHEN 1 THEN 0.18
            END)
    , 0)) AS leRank2
FROM
    us3r U
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    assets_animals C ON
        C.user_id = U.id
WHERE           
    C.assets_animal_name IN ('cats','dogs','birds','rats','horses','cows')
GROUP BY
    U.id
```

Let us know if that helps with the performance.

Comment: Really great. See my edit. Thanks for the REGEX/IN tips. Using the count outside allowed me to make 6 counts instead of 10 inside the COALESCEs.